# running X86 Virtualbox VM on an Apple silicon Mac, UTM not working

Tags: linux, qemu, arm, x86

My college provides a virtual machine ([SliTaz](https://www.slitaz.org/en/) VM, possibly an old Linux distro) to run veriluoc which is a software to design and simulate logic gates. The problem is that VM was designed to run on x86/x86_64  hardware. But I need it to run it on my M2-based(Arm) Macbook. I have been trying to use qemu and UTM to run it, with no success. The exact problem UTM displays is:

```
Booting SliTaz GNU/Linux (cooking) (Kernel vmlinux-2.6.37-slitaz)
Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
   [Linux-bzImage, setup=0x3400, size=0x25d4a0]
ehci_hcd 000:00:1d.7: init 0000:00:1d.7 fail, -16
i8042.c: No controller found.
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
Pid: 1, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.37-slitaz #2
Call Trace:
 [<c1378153>] ? printk+0xf/0x11
 [<c1378048>] panic +0x50/0x14b
 [<c1507b55>] mount_block_root+0x1e5/0x1f9
 [<c108a698>］？sys_mknod+Ox13/0x15
 [<c1507c6e>] mount_root+0x4c/0x54
 [<c1507db6>1 prepare_namespace+0x140/0x171
 [<c15078ad>] kernel_init+0x17f/0x18e
 [<c150772e>] ? kernel_int+0×0/0×18e
 [<c1003a76>] kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10
```

No success either after searching the term `VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`, or changing the disk type.

Comment: Do you mean [Verilog](https://www.verilog.com/)

Comment: no, its not code based, it is like pspice but for logic gates

Comment: A little bit of Decoding: `ehci` is The Enhanced Hardware Controller Interface, which is the initiator for USB 2.0.  It looks like EHCI passed control after failure to `i8042` which is the Port Driver for PS/2 connected mice, which won't be found either.  The root mount may be failing to mount because of or in combination with having issues with the "fake HDD"

Comment: Following what you said I have disabled USB 2.0 and forced PS/2 (both were checkmarks on UTM) now both errors have disappeared but it stil fails to mount. Will changing the drive type work?

Comment: I and other readers have improved your post.  I did find your distribution believe it or not, and linked it in the post.  There is an ARM version for the Pi4, but we still may be stuck.  As for changing the HDD type, start at the top, choose the 1st option, boot the VM.  If fail, uncheck first, check next.  Keep repeating until you find one that works.

Comment: Thanks for making my post better, i’ll look into the Pi4 thing more

Comment: Hi Philip, i do not know how to change from one hypervisor to another nor can i see such option in the vm settings pannel on UTM. Where could I find the boot loader? I’m so sorry but I don’t know how to modify the image.

Comment: @PhilipCouling While researching VerilUOC_Desktop I found a slide presentation.  It seems that this "updated software" is only available inside this VM named DigitalEngineering VM, and it's only available on online course websites affiliated with Spain and Portugal.  It was launched in VirtualBox5 and looked to be 32-bit only.  See [here](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/digital-systems/introduction-to-veriluoc-desktop-i-logisim-and-verilcirc-ebAVp). Every time I try to zoom it gets pixelated.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Continued.  It looks as if someone published an update to [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/history.html) post the author's death/without his approval and seems to have buried it in this VM.  Development was suspended in 2011.

Comment: @NilOller We don't care where your from.  Just gathering all the information for all of us.  Whatever the update is that's contained in the VM is only available inside that VM, but the software that I linked earlier is what the software inside is based on.

Comment: Ok, i will try searching based on that, thank you

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include what you did to convert the VM and run it on qemu. Include commands you used.